# How to clear cache,swap and what are the limits?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ram

I am trying to run Docker but I need more memory on my Ubuntu 16.04

```
 free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7914        4024        3072          83         817        3448
Swap:          8127          14        8113
```

When I run docker

```
Setting advertised host to 127.0.0.1.
Operating system RAM available is 3344 MiB, which is less than the lowest
recommended of 5120 MiB. Your system performance may be seriously impacted.
```

What should I do to get more RAM?Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to identify those process using the most memory and decide whether they can be stopped to retrieve memory or not. The top command will help you in this instance. Alternatively, you can vertically scale your system and add more memory to the system.

Comment: Ok.I have decided to kill pid with Cassandra Java,that akes 25% memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below command to identify top 10 Memory consuming resources. so that you can trouble accordingly

```
ps axo %mem,command,pid| sort -nr | head
```

To drop cache use below command

```
sync;echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```